What did socrates believe in after life and what he actually said?
I am reading the book of Bart Ehrman's Heaven and Hell. In there, I might have hit some controversies that may not be controversies at all, but my mind can't decide.
In Apology, socrate says:

Death is one of two things. Either it is annihilation, and the dead
have no consciousness of anything, or, as we are told, it is really a
change — a migration of the soul from this place to another.

What's interesting is Socrates uses the saying: "If what we're told is true" when talking about souls going to another place. This brings a controversy whether socrates himself believed that after life exists or not. "If what we're told is true" kind of confirms that Socrates is not sure that after life exists.
In phaedo, there's a myth portrayed about what happens when soul goes to after life - i.e when they meet Tarturus or go to acherusian lake.
Question: Who tells the story of this myth ? Is it socrates or Plato ? If it's socrates, then can you explain why he would say this if he is not sure about whether after life exists or not ? Remember his words in apology about souls: "if what we're told is true". Bart in his book says that it's socrates that tells this story.

Generally speaking its not very useful to separate Socrates and Plato since we have little data of Socrates outside of what Plato wrote. And Plato identified so strongly with Socrates as his teacher (guru) that even if Plato pushes his own thoughts into Socrates' mouth he does it with the sense This is what Socrates would/might say... This answer is somewhat in the same direction

Thanks for your answer. My confusion is that if socrates really described after life journey(Tarturus or go to acherusian lake), then he must have believed in after life ? If so, why would he say in apology - "if what we are told is true" about soul migration ? "if what we are told is true" definitely confirms even more that he is hedging and doesn't believe in after life

hedge ≠ believe; Also hedge ≠ dont believe. In fact hedge ≠ "I dont know" which is really Socrates trademark.  Hedge is a protection gesture whereas I-dont-know is an openness gesture. Socrates asserts that death holds for him no fear because he does not know what it entails And how can one fear an unknown entity? He in fact gently chides those near him for weeping because they are falling into the error of imagining they know and therefore concocting fear in themselves and sorrow towards Socrates

Ah, so in your opinion, just because he hedged by:"if what we are told is true", that doesn't mean he doesn't believe in after life. Got it. but if "Socrates asserts that death holds for him no fear because he does not know what it entails", since he doesn't know, then after-life journey myth dialogue by him is just what he believes ? I guess, we could entail that socrates believed in after-life and myth he proposed is how he looks at after life - i.e so I guess, my most important question is: he believed in hell-heaven, didn't he ?

@JulioDiEgidio definitely, my bad. I should have said: "as we are told". In this case as well, my question remains the same, but as Rushi answered, hedge doesn't mean that he didn't believe in after-life as well as others.

I have retracted my comment, but I am still not sure what you are asking.  Indeed (and with all due respect), I only partly concur with @Rushi, surely on what Socrates is (purportedly) saying, not so much on Socrates' attitude (Know Thyself more than I Don't Know), especially as contrasted to Plato-nism and what follows.  But, as said, I am still not sure what you are actually/exactly asking, or maybe claiming.

He believed in hell-heaven, didn't he?  Hell-Heaven are very very Christian ideologies.  On the other hand some kind of after-life is universally believed. Socrates clearly believed in an after-life or more exactly "before-life". Phaedrus — immortality of soul . Meno — the slave boy who does not know geometry correctly proves a theorem. Socrates suggests it is "recollection". And of course Phaedo — Socrates at his death is calm and collected because of the immortality of his soul. He asserts that all of philosophy is about recollecting Truth from earlier lives

Ultimately whatever religious dispensation you adhere to the belief in God and belief in soul are complementary —  Father (= Son) = (Holy) Spirit in the Christian dispensation. In Hinduism the equivalent is God (=Guru) =Atma.

@ScottRowe Surely a schoolboy struggling with a physics problem is not equivalent to Einstein (or if you prefer tinkering with his bicycle equivalent to Edison). Do not different people have vastly different contributions to the overall human collective?  Some 40 thousand of people have died in a war in the last 8 months. Very likely none of it would have happening if only one death had not happened on 4th Nov 1995

@ScottRowe So it's not worth asking a question about what Socrates believed ? you mention that 100,000,000,000 humans have been born after that which is true, but 99.99% of them are uninteresting people that don't interest me(including you) or anyone learning philosophy. I am sorry but that's the truth :)

@Rushi Definitely, Hell-Heaven is just a term, but since on Phaedo, Socrates is describing Tarturus and Acherusian lake, he believed in the after-life where rewards/punishments would take place. That's what I was mostly curious.

Need to change my position. Tartarus and Acherusian lake correspond quite closely and are likely the inspirations for Christian hell and purgatory

@Rushi now we know whom to blame.
